# Errors inserting values (such as URLs) into MySQL database WITH a URL

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on my website and I can't access myPhpAdmin right now, so I tried making a script for inserting values for a search thing. However, when I visit the link, `website.com/search/create.php?l=link&d=description&t=title`, I get an error. This one

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'link, description, title)' at line 1
```

Here's what my script looks like.

```
$link = "https://website.com";
$description = "The homepage of the site";
$title = "Home";

// sql to create table
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (link, description, title) VALUES (".$link.", ".$description.", ".$title.")";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "it's working";
} else {
echo "it's not working?" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: **SQL Injection**  Little Bobby Tables https://xkcd.com/327/   Open Web Application Security Project https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection  (Answers suggesting single quotes be incorporated into the SQL text are incomplete if they don't also suggest properly escaping potentially unsafe values. Best practice is prepared statements with bind placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (link, description, title) VALUES ('".$link."', '".$description."', '".$title."')";
```

instead of :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (link, description, title) VALUES (".$link.", ".$description.", ".$title.")";
```

you are trying to insert a string without '

Answer (score 0):

Just Change the Query syntax in your code and check it ... Hope your error should be resolve.

```
// sql to create table
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (link, description, title) VALUES ('$link', '$description', '$title')";
```

Comment: its change inserted value.create extra `dot` in values like `.text.`

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are missing single quotation in SQL query, try the following:-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (link, description, title) VALUES ('".$link.", '".$description."', '".$title."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for inserting data into database table is wrong (assuming you already executed database connection query ($conn) and have 'search' table on database).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (link, description, title) VALUES ('$link', '$description', '$title')";
```

You don't have to put concatenate operator ('.') inside your SQL query as you are not concatenating PHP and markup texts.